# Disabling a array of textbox when any one textbox have a value

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

how can i disable all textbox if any one of textbox have a value?? I have array of cost_type and its cost, if any of the cost enterd.. all the other textboxes for cost_type should be disable.if no cost entered.. all text field should be editable. I already try this code but its not working.

```
function stoppedTyping(iVal){
        var costs=document.getElementsByName("cost")[iVal].value;
        if(costs > 0) { 
        document.getElementById("cost_" + iVal).disabled=true;
        } else { 
                document.getElementById("cost_" + iVal).disabled=false;
        }
    }

<td colspan="4">
         <input type="text" size="10"  maxlength="8" name="cost" id="cost_<c:out value="${y}"/>"  value="<c:out value="${costDto.cost}"/>" 
                        onBlur=" stoppedTyping(<c:out value="${y}"/>)"; "/>
                       </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking the length of the value:

```
var costs = document.getElementsByName("cost")[iVal].value;

if(costs.length > 0) { 

}
```

or a little more compact:

```
var costs = document.getElementsByName("cost")[iVal].value;
document.getElementById("cost_" + iVal).disabled = costs.length > 0;
```

Comment: i have updated the question.. i want to disable all the textbox if any of the cost enterd in the textbox.

Comment: Something like [this](https://codepen.io/Mobius1/pen/gWdEVb?editors=0010)?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your script.

```
$('.enableToggle').on('keyup paste', function(){
    var curVal = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g,'').length > 0;
    $(this).siblings('.enableToggle').prop('disabled', curVal);
});
```

and add `class="enableToggle"` to all your input fields.